# Visualizing users by applications based on their transactions

Tags: python, plotly, visualization, networkx, bokeh

I have a data set which consists of user email, application they accessed and amount of data transfer happened during that transaction. I wanted to visualize this data as a network chart where users accessing a certain app would appear closer to the application node compared to others.
Here is the sample data:

```
d = pd.DataFrame({'Employee Email':['abc@xyz.com','abc@xyz.com','abc@xyz.com','def@xyz.com','lmn@xyz.com','abc@xyz.com'],
              'Application':['SAP','SFDC','SAP','SFDC','Tableau','Tableau'],
              'Transactions':[10,20,50,78,90,22]
})
```

I was able to create a network chart but would like to make it interactive and add the above mentioned functionality of resizing edges based on transaction amount. Following is my sample code:

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
user_app_transactions = d.groupby(['Employee Email','Application'])['Transactions'].sum().reset_index()
G = nx.Graph()
# Add nodes for users
users = user_app_transactions['Employee Email'].unique()
G.add_nodes_from(users, node_color='lightblue')
# Add nodes for applications
applications = user_app_transactions['Application'].unique()
G.add_nodes_from(applications, node_color='lightgreen')
# Add edges connecting users and applications
edges = [(user, app) for user, app in user_app_transactions[['Employee Email', 'Application']].values]
G.add_edges_from(edges)
# Set node positions for users and applications
pos = nx.spring_layout(G, seed=42)
# Draw nodes and edges
nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G, pos, node_color='lightblue', node_size=200, label='Users')
nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G, pos, nodelist=applications, node_color='lightgreen', node_size=300, label='Applications')
nx.draw_networkx_edges(G, pos, alpha=0.5)
# Label nodes
nx.draw_networkx_labels(G, pos, font_size=8)
# Set plot title and legend
plt.title('Adjacency Relationship: Users and Applications')
plt.legend()
# Show the plot
plt.axis('off')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Any suggestions are highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to create a `bokeh` figure using `networkx`, see the [`from_networkx` example](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/examples/topics/graph/from_networkx.html).

But there are some downsides:

1. bokeh can not convert strings like `'abc@xyz.com'` into a valid position
2. it is not so easy to get the position of the nodes and place the text

```
import networkx as nx
import pandas as pd

from bokeh.palettes import Category20_20
from bokeh.models import LabelSet,HoverTool
from bokeh.plotting import figure, from_networkx, show, output_notebook
output_notebook()

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Employee Email':['abc@xyz.com','abc@xyz.com','abc@xyz.com','def@xyz.com','lmn@xyz.com','abc@xyz.com'],
    'Application': ['SAP','SFDC','SAP','SFDC','Tableau','Tableau'],
    'Transactions':[10,20,50,78,90,22]
})

# get unique ids for problem 1
unique_employees = df['Employee Email'].unique()
emp_mapper = {k: i for i, k in enumerate()}
app_mapper = {k: i for i, k in enumerate(df['Application'].unique(), start=len(df))}
df['Emp'] = df['Employee Email'].apply(lambda x: emp_mapper[x])
df['App'] = df['Application'].apply(lambda x: app_mapper[x])
user_app_transactions = user_app_transactions = df.groupby(['Employee Email','Application'])[['Transactions', 'Emp', 'App']].sum().reset_index()
user_app_transactions
print(user_app_transactions)
>>>
  Employee Email Application  Transactions  Emp  App
0    abc@xyz.com         SAP            60    0   12
1    abc@xyz.com        SFDC            20    0    7
2    abc@xyz.com     Tableau            22    0    8
3    def@xyz.com        SFDC            78    1    7
4    lmn@xyz.com     Tableau            90    2    8

# create a networks graph G
G = nx.Graph()
edges = []
emp_nodes = []
app_nodes = []
for emp_email, app_str, _, emp, app in user_app_transactions.values:
    if not emp_email in emp_nodes:
        G.add_nodes_from([emp], colors='lightblue', hover=emp_email)
        emp_nodes.append(emp_email)
    if not app_str in app_nodes:
        G.add_nodes_from([app], colors='lightgreen', hover=app_str)
        emp_nodes.append(app_str)
    edges.append((emp, app))
G.add_edges_from(edges)

# create a bokeh figure
p = figure(x_range=(-2, 2), y_range=(-2, 2), x_axis_location=None, y_axis_location=None)
p.grid.grid_line_color = None

graph = from_networkx(G, nx.spring_layout, scale=1.8, center=(0,0))
graph.node_renderer.glyph.update(size=20, fill_color="colors")
p.renderers.append(graph)

# get the positions of the nodes for the text (problem 2)
text_x_pos = []
text_y_pos = []
for x, y in graph.layout_provider.graph_layout.values():
    text_x_pos.append(x)
    text_y_pos.append(y)

hover = graph.node_renderer.data_source.data['hover']

p.text(x=text_x_pos, y=text_y_pos, text=hover, y_offset=8,
       text_font_size="12px", text_color="#555555",
       text_align='center', text_font_style='bold')

p.add_tools(
    HoverTool(
        tooltips=[("Info", "@hover")],
        renderers=[graph],
    )
)
show(p)
```

[image: result graph]

Answer (score 0):

I actually found out a better way to visualize the information using R script and hierarchical edge bundling technique. Following is the sample code:

```
d1 <- data.frame(from="origin", to=paste("Dept", seq(1,5), sep=""))
d1 <- rbind(d1,c('origin','application'))
d2<-data.frame(from=c('Dept1','Dept2','Dept3','Dept4','Dept5','application','application','application'),to=c('example1@abc.com','example2@abc.com','example3@abc.com','example4@abc.com','example5@abc.com','App1','App2','App3'))
edges <-rbind(d1,d2)
d1<- data.frame(from='origin',to=paste("Dept",seq(1,5),sep=""))
d_1 <- data.frame(from=rep(d1$to,each=5),to=paste(paste('email',seq(1,100),sep=""),'@abc.com',sep=""))
d_1<-sample_n(d_1, 20)

d_2 <- data.frame(from=rep('application',each=5),to=paste('App',seq(1,100),sep=""))
d_2<-sample_n(d_2, 20)


d1 <- rbind(d1,c('origin','application'))

d2<-rbind(d_1,d_2)
edges <-rbind(d1,d2)
all_leaves<- unique(d2$to)

connect<- rbind(
  data.frame(from=sample(head(d_1$to),15,replace=T), to=sample(tail(d_2$to),15,replace=T)),
  data.frame(from=sample(tail(d_1$to),15,replace=T), to=sample(head(d_2$to),15,replace=T)),
  data.frame(from=sample(d_1$to,15,replace=T), to=sample(d_2$to,15,replace=T)),
  data.frame(from=sample(d_1$to,15,replace=T), to=sample(d_2$to,15,replace=T))
)
connect$value <- runif(nrow(connect))
#connect

vertices  <-  data.frame(
  name = unique(c(as.character(edges$from), as.character(edges$to)))
)
vertices$value <-runif(nrow(vertices))
vertices$group <-edges$from[ match( vertices$name, edges$to ) ]

vertices$id <- NA
myleaves <- which(is.na(match(vertices$name, edges$from) ))
nleaves <- length(myleaves)
vertices$id[ myleaves ] <- seq(1:nleaves)
vertices$angle <- 90 - 360 * vertices$id / nleaves

# calculate the alignment of labels: right or left
# If I am on the left part of the plot, my labels have currently an angle < -90
vertices$hjust <- ifelse( vertices$angle < -90, 1, 0)

# flip angle BY to make them readable
vertices$angle <- ifelse(vertices$angle < -90, vertices$angle+180, vertices$angle)

mygraph <- igraph::graph_from_data_frame( edges, vertices=vertices )

# The connection object must refer to the ids of the leaves:
from  <-  match( connect$from, vertices$name)
to  <-  match( connect$to, vertices$name)
options(repr.plot.width=15, repr.plot.height=8)
# Basic usual argument
p<-ggraph(mygraph, layout = 'dendrogram', circular = TRUE) +
  geom_node_point(aes(filter = leaf, x = x*1.05, y=y*1.05,colour=group, size=value, alpha=0.2)) +
  geom_conn_bundle(data = get_con(from = from, to = to), alpha=0.2, colour="skyblue", width=0.9) +
  geom_node_text(aes(x = x*1.1, y=y*1.1, filter = leaf, label=name, angle = angle, hjust=hjust), size=4, alpha=1.5) +

  theme_void() +
  theme(
    legend.position="none",
    plot.margin=unit(c(0,0,0,0),"cm"),
  ) +
 expand_limits(x = c(1, 1), y = c(1, 1))
p
```

[image]